# How to get the row index number of the cell of a dynamically generated table using Jquery on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an automatically generated table using jquery. I need to get the index number of the row on a keyup event in a cell of that table. this is what i have tried. so far no luck. here is my code

Jquery

```
$(document).on('keyup change','.unit_price',function(){
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var price = $(this).val();          
        price = parseInt(price);
        var rownumber = $('#protable').index(tr);
        alert(rownumber);
}
```

HTML

```
<table id ="protable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Is Ordered</th> 
                    <th>Check List Item</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th> 
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>        
                </tr>
 </table>
```

My goal is to automatically calculate the total price by multiplying unit price and quantity. please help me out

Comment: you are aplying the keyup and change events to the html items with class unitprice and in your html there's not a single element with this class

Comment: @AlbertoCh. apparently there are. they are generated using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally got it. it was very simple actually.

```
$(document).on('keyup change','.unit_price',function(){
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $(this).val();          
    price = parseInt(price);
    var rownumber = tr.index();
}
```